# There is no available editor for "........Form1.cs" Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, editor

I have finished my works on a project and then shut computer. Morning when I open the project there was nothing inside it. I tried to right clicked Form1.cs then I got an error saying "There is no editor available for ".........Form1.cs" Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed"

And now I can't access my code at all. I'm using Visual C# 2012. I tried opening it directly and it brings up C# but the .cs file opens up in notepad.and there is nothing in notepad.

I shocked because I am very new on coding and don't know what to do. So, Is there a way to get back my project again? Please help!

Comment: Go to the folder location where your project was created and see if the files are still there. If they are all still there, try to open the solution/project from there.

Comment: The .sln file is where I created. I clicked it already and it is opened. But I can not start the project. Because the Form1.cs does not work. When I right click to View Code, I am getting the error "There is no editor available for ".........Form1.cs" Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! It seems like your project files mey got corrupted. I suggest you try and search in your start menu for Visual Studio 2012. 
Check some other random files to see if they got deleted or corrputed.
If VS does not exist, try reinstalling it.

Best of Regards,
Itay

Tip: Back your pc up each few months :) It will help to avoid cases like the following.

Comment: The other projects are still working on VS. But only the last one is lost. I just repaired the Visual Studio and nothing changed for the last project. the problem is still same.

Comment: Well, if you didn't write much, i guess you can start over. When I develop on my crappy laptop - this happens some times...